Where do we get $\Delta U = nC_vT$ from?

The change in internal energy at constant volume is $Q=nC_v\Delta T$
Why does the same equation apply for constant pressure?

Does this answer your question? Why is $ \Delta U = mc_v \Delta T$ applicable in non-constant volume processes (ideal gas )

I wrote a note called The cruelest equation in introductory thermodynamics to discuss the presence of the constant-volume heat capacity in equations describing gases at constant pressure (among other conditions). Perhaps something there will be of use to you.

For an ideal gas (which is what the author is referring to), internal energy is independent of pressure.
